# how to add parallelism for flux in spring web Flux

Tags: spring, parallel-processing, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, flux

```
@Transactional
public Flux<Todo> createTodos(Flux<Todo> todos) {

        return todos.map(todo -> new TodoToEntityTransformer().apply(todo))
                .collectList()
                .map(todoEntities -> {
                    todoEntities = todoRepository.saveAll(todoEntities);
                    todoRepository.flush();
                    return todoRepository.findAllById(todoEntities.parallelStream().map(todoEntity -> todoEntity.getTodoId()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                })
                .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
                .map(todoEntity -> new EntityToTodoTransformer().apply(todoEntity));
}
```

we have to add parallelism for this topic. can someone help me?

Comment: you have several problems, creating a new `TodoToEntityTransformer` is a memory waste, you could just use a static method `TodoTransformer#toEntity`. Calling a database using JPA is blocking, and flushing is blocking. All blocking calls (like JPA database calls) should be assigned their own scheduler https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking going back into the database to just fetch what you added is a waste of resources. after saving return and use a `then` statement and just return the orginal `Flux<Todos>`. and use flatmap and not map if you want asynchronity

Comment: In additional to Thomas' comment, for beginning you should switch to https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc